# java lwjgl No OpenGL context found in the current thread

Tags: java, opengl, display

I having trouble with lwjgl getting a display to open. This worked before I upgraded to windows 10. (I had windows 7 before).

here is the error from the console

```
org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated
at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:247)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:797)
at com.asasse.game3d.renderengine.DisplayManager.createDisplay(DisplayManager.java:23)
at com.asasse.game3d.enginetester.MainGameLoop.main(MainGameLoop.java:22)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
at org.lwjgl.opengl.GLContext.getCapabilities(GLContext.java:124)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glViewport(GL11.java:3261)
at com.asasse.game3d.renderengine.DisplayManager.createDisplay(DisplayManager.java:31)
at com.asasse.game3d.enginetester.MainGameLoop.main(MainGameLoop.java:22)
```

here if my code from my project thas's causing the error

```
     final ContextAttribs attribs = new ContextAttribs(3, 1).withForwardCompatible(true);

    try {

        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        Display.create(new PixelFormat(), attribs);

    } catch (final LWJGLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    GL11.glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
```

the width is 1280 and the height is 720

Answer (score 1):

try using this instead:

```
ContextAttribs attribs = new ContextAttribs(3,3)
        .withForwardCompatible(true)
        .withProfileCore(true);

        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH,HEIGHT));
            Display.create(new PixelFormat(),attribs);
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

My guess is that your version is too low for some calculation and therefore threw an Exception.

**If that didn't work**, it might be that your Graphics Driver is **outdated** for Windows 10. Try upgrading your driver. (you can see your driver by typing dxdiag after pressing `windows + R`)